# OpenGL rotation around local axis not working as designed

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glm-math

I want to rotate an object around its local axis. First I calculate the local axis by the `transform.rotation` vector (x - pitch, y - yaw, z - roll).

```
glm::vec3 front;
front.x = cos(glm::radians(transform.rotation.y)) * cos(glm::radians(transform.rotation.x));
front.y = sin(glm::radians(transform.rotation.x));
front.z = sin(glm::radians(transform.rotation.y)) * cos(glm::radians(transform.rotation.x));
transform.front = glm::normalize(front);
transform.right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(transform.front, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)));
transform.up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(transform.right, transform.front));
```

And then I set the model matrix as follows.

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::translate(model, transform.position);

model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(transform.rotation.x), transform.right);
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(transform.rotation.y), transform.up);
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(transform.rotation.z), transform.front);

model = glm::scale(model, transform.scale);
shader.setMat4("model", model);
```

The only one that seems to be working is the yaw rotation, the roll performs as pitch and the pitch as roll, and almost any tweak makes the object rotate in any direction but the specified one. The others just not rotate in the expected way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `model*=glm::rotate()`? Since it looks like you're resetting the matrix on all those transformations.

Comment: @John No it is not. `model` is an input to `glm::rotate()`. Pleas read the documentation before you guess. See [`glm::rotate()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4.)